# Pattern match output of terminal command (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, terminal

How can I pattern match the output of a command?

For example, I need to run the following command :

```
nginx -V
```

Which returns the following :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads
```

I need to match everything after the term 'command arguments:'
Then I need to append a string to the end of the matched string
And finally I need to run a new command

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There is no _'command arguments:'_ in your output.

Comment: Use `grep` and/or `sed`.

Answer (score -1):

This might work :

```
eval "nginx -V | grep 'configure arguments: ' | sed -n -e 's/^configure arguments: /begining command /; s/$/ end string/p'"
```

It greps the right line, replaces `configure arguments:` with the starting
command and appends at the end a string, finally prints the result as a string
that is executed.